# What Software Is Used For Autonomy Software Simulation?

Tags: slam, simulation, path-planning, software

I don't have a physical robot but I would like to test the performance of my C++ code for odometry, SLAM, and path planning. Are there any good simulation software where I can test my algorithm implementation?

Answer (score 3):

There are quite a lot options for this, each with different features, strengths and weaknesses. A few examples:

- [Gazebo](http://gazebosim.org/) (as mentioned by [edwinem](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/a/20142/)): very well known in the robotics community, some would say it's a little bit dated
- [Microsoft Airsim](https://microsoft.github.io/AirSim/) (also mentioned by [edwinem](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/a/20142/)): originally developed for autonomous drones and autonomous driving, uses the unreal engine for high image quality (experimental support for Unity)
- [NVIDIA Isaac SDK](https://developer.nvidia.com/isaac-sdk): a "newcomer" with a lot of manpower from NVIDIA in the background where the focus is more on indoor applications, also has the ability to [work with ROS](https://docs.nvidia.com/isaac/isaac/apps/samples/navigation_rosbridge/doc/ros.html). It uses the Unity engine for high quality image rendering (Unreal support was planned, but doesn't seem to get pursued at the moment)
- [webots](https://cyberbotics.com/): general purpose simulator with quite a few robot models included, has C++ and Python APIs and is known to work with ROS
- [robotbenchmark](https://robotbenchmark.net/): builds on webots and allows you to develop your skills in different challenges presented on the website (note: the robot is programmed in Python, not C++)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to test everything together then you need to setup a simulator like [Gazebo](http://gazebosim.org/)(integrates well with ROS which I assume you are using). Other options could be [Airsim](https://github.com/microsoft/AirSim), or some custom simulator. These options though and are more involved in required setup on your part.

**Testing separately:**

SLAM is pretty easy to test. Just download some dataset such as [KITTI](http://www.cvlibs.net/datasets/kitti/eval_odometry.php), or [Euroc](https://projects.asl.ethz.ch/datasets/doku.php?id=kmavvisualinertialdatasets), and test your algorithm on their data.

For path planning I would take a look at what [OMPL](https://ompl.kavrakilab.org/integration.html) integrates into, and setup your code in the same way.